# Convert CloudFormation template (YAML) to Troposphere code

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, troposphere

I have a large sized CloudFormation template written in Yaml, I want to start using Troposphere instead. Is there any easy way to convert the CF template to Troposphere code?

I have noticed this script here https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere/blob/master/troposphere/template_generator.py
This creates a Troposphere python object, but I am not sure if its possible to output it Troposphere code.

Comment: I'm curious why @SamAnthony. I have inherited large set of Troposphere templates and I'm wondering why we don't just use YAML instead!

Comment: @spinkus I think regular YAML CloudFormation is still a decent option. It appears that the Troposphere will detected mistakes in the template which regular YAML would not. Example a typing mistake in a parameter name might not be caught until the YAML template is actually "executed" where as Troposphere may have detected this sooner. I also had one situation where a Python/Troposphere for loop eliminated the need to a huge YAML template with many repeated elements.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by converting the CF YAML to JSON and running the https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere/blob/master/scripts/cfn2py passing the JSON file in as an argument.

Comment: I don't see a way to pass the file name to the script

Comment: python cfn2py filename.py

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the good tip from @OllieB

Install dependencies using pip or poetry:

- https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installation
- https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere
- https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cfn-template-flip

```sh
pip install 'troposphere[policy]'
pip install cfn-flip
```

```sh
poetry add -D 'troposphere[policy]'
poetry add -D cfn-flip
```

The command line conversion is something like:

```sh
cfn-flip -c -j template-vpc.yaml template-vpc.json
cfn2py template-vpc.json > template_vpc.py
```

WARNING: it appears that the `cfn2py` script might not be fully unit tested or something, because it can generate some code that does not pass troposphere validations.  I recommend adding a simple round-trip test to the end of the output python script, e.g.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":

    template_py = json.loads(t.to_json())

    with open("template-vpc.json", "r") as json_fd:
        template_cfn = json.load(json_fd)

    assert template_py == template_cfn
```

See also https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere/issues/1879 for an example of auto-generation of pydantic models from CFN json schemas.

Comment: An example TypeError bug report is in https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere/issues/1878

Answer (score 0):

```
from troposphere.template_generator import TemplateGenerator
import yaml

with open("aws/cloudformation/template.yaml") as f:
    source_content = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.BaseLoader)
    template = TemplateGenerator(source_content)
```

This snippet shall give you a template object from Troposphere library. You can then make modifications using Troposphere api.